# pyspark Datetype() during creation of the dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

here is my source code in a databricks notebook using python

```
data = [('2021-01-01','2021-01-02')]   
schema1 = StructType([
StructField("date1", DateType(), True),
StructField("date2", DateType(), True)])
spark.createDataFrame(data,schema1).show()
```

however I got the following error
[image]

anyone has the idea ?

Comment: Hint: Spark has no idea how to parse this date. You need to provide this information.

Answer (score 3):

You tried to inject string type data into date type so you failed.

I see two solutions:

1. Use date type data

```
import datetime

data = [(
    datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d").date(),
    datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-01-02', "%Y-%m-%d").date()
)]   

schema1 = StructType([
StructField("date1", DateType(), True),
StructField("date2", DateType(), True)])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema1)

df.show()

# output:
+----------+----------+
|     date1|     date2|
+----------+----------+
|2021-01-01|2021-01-02|
+----------+----------+
```

2. Don't use schema at first, convert into date type later

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [('2021-01-01','2021-01-02')] 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df = df.select(*(F.to_date(c) for c in df.columns))

df.show()

# oudput
+-----------+-----------+
|to_date(_1)|to_date(_2)|
+-----------+-----------+
| 2021-01-01| 2021-01-02|
+-----------+-----------+
```